# Where do I enter meta-information on the Careers site?

Tags: support, jobs

In Norway, all CV's include some basic information like:

- Date of birth
- Contact details, phone numbers

Where do I enter this information on the Careers site?

Answer (score 2):

There is no designated space for this, I would be inclined to enter it in the "personal statement" field so it will display with the rest of your information. Alternatively you could enter it in the "background" field at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Date of Birth is usually frowned upon in America, as it can open the business up to liability ('age discrimination'). I'd recommend not putting it in.

Contact information can be placed in the Background field, or in your personal statement.

Comment: In some (other) countries a DoB on your CV is normal/expected. Also, marital status ... and maybe a photograph too. The OP is in Norway.

Comment: @ChrisW then if such a thing is ever implemented, then it'd be country specific, or at least give a warning that in the US, you probably don't want to include it. For your photograph, you can use your gravatar. See my profile for an example: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker.  Marital status? Age? Why the heck does an employer need to know that stuff?

Comment: In some countries Age and Marital Status has tax implications for the employer. Also depending on the type of position, some companies will not higher people in a certain age bracket certain positions, and it has an impact on your years of experience. I have CV's come past my desk where guys have 8 years dev experience, but they in the 18 - 21 year old age bracket.

Comment: a CV, particularly in Europe is supposed to describe the applicant more holistically, including some personal details.

Comment: "Why the heck does an employer need to know that stuff?" - Coming from North America myself, it surprised+shocked me to discover that; nevertheless, it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The way Careers works is that when an employer finds your CV (though the paid candidate search) and decides you are worth contacting, you receive the message via email (and it also shows up in the SE "inbox"). You then have the choice of replying to the message (or ignoring it) and marking your stance towards the <s>company</s> *position you were messaged about* as **Interested** or **Not interested**. If you reply and choose "interested", the employer will get your email address and you can continue talks from there, using whichever medium that suits both parties.

Of course, you can *also* make your CV publicly visible on the web, and if you wish, you can add your contact info or any other details to the free textfields, as George and Korneel pointed out. (And I think it does make sense to have some contact info there.) Personally I mention my email in "personal statement" section, but have left out other contact info and date of birth (although those often appear in traditional CVs here in Finland too).

Comment: Speaking of traditional CVs or resumes: I've decided not to bother with those anymore (I mean maintaining a separate document and sending it around as email attachment, etc). I just have my LinkedIn profile and Careers CV online (interlinked), and from my experience so far, I'm not going back to the old way. If some employer *really* wants that .doc or .pdf, submitted through a form, we probably weren't meant for each other anyway :)